# Any way to change path that python module is imported from?

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to import a module called ee with

```
import ee
```

However, after running the script, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geebam.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "geebam.py", line 78, in main
    ee.Initialize()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Initialize'
```

I know for a fact that the ee module has an Initialize function in its __init.py__.  So next I tried printing out the module's path with

```
print(ee.__file__)
```

resulting in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ee-0.2-py2.7.egg/ee/__init__.pyc
```

However, the module I want to import is in:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ee
```

I'm actually pretty unclear about how I got the .egg file, so I'm not sure if I'll be okay just deleting it.  Is there any way to specify to python that I want ee to be imported from an alternate path?

Comment: Might point you in the right direction.  I had to do stuff like this:  import sys
sys.path.append('../library/')
from filetools import LocationInfo   to get custom packages imported

Comment: Easiest (but also stupid) way: `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ee")`. Go about your day

Comment: You can use sys.path.append() before your import statement in able to append path you want.

Comment: Don't modify `sys.path`.  Try to remove the .egg installation using pip, and if that fails, just delete the directory.